# Sails JS - How to connect a user api model to the user bucket in Couchbase?

Tags: node.js, sails.js, couchbase

I have a `User.js` model and a `UserController.js` controller in a `Sail.Js` application. I set the below config in the `connections.js` file:

```
CB: {
  adapter: 'sails-cbes',
  host: 'http://localhost',
  port: 8091,
  user: 'couchbase',
  password: 'couchbase',
  operationTimeout: 60,    

  bucket: {
    name: 'user'
  }
```

Also, I added the `connection: 'CB'.bucket` to the `models.js` config file.

There is no error when I lift the application using `sails lift` command, but my model still read and write the data to the sails-memory database instead of the user bucket in Couchbase. Is there something I'm missing to read and write the data on Couchbase?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my guess on what is happening to you. Check in the config folder and see if you have an env folder, in there you have two files (development.js and production.js).  Make sure you have:

```
models: {
   connection: 'yourconnectionname'
}
```

Generally I work off of a different connection on development and production.  Let me know if this was your problem.

Comment: I added your config to `development.js`, but no success. I tried to use the exact config as `sails-cbes` documentation like `  cb: {
    adapter: 'sails-cbes',
    host: 'http://127.0.0.1',
    port: 8091,
    user: 'couchbase',
    password: 'couchbase',

    bucket: {
        name: 'user',
        pass: ''
    }
` in `connections.js` file, but I'm getting the errors `A hook (`orm`) failed to load` and `Error: Failed to connect to the Couchbase/ElasticSearch clients { [Error: failed to connect to bucket] code: 25 }`